# Why tablet can't be a mobile display or minotor?

Tags: mac-mini, tablet

Is it possible that tablet can be a mobile monitor? So I can connect my Mac mini to it through    HDMI port.

Comment: What tablet? Please make clare what wyou want to do.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI ports are not bidirectional when sending audio/video.  The HDMI port on your tablet is output only, so that you can connect it to a TV or monitor.  You will not be able to use it as a second monitor in that way.  However, there are alternatives that would allow you to do so, depending on the tablet's OS and hardware.  That is a whole different animal, however.

Comment: "That is a whole different animal, however." - Well, he wanted a Minotaur and that's half-animal anyway... :P